# Errors with a curl request to kibana

Tags: curl, kibana, elk

I have a functional elk stack v6.8 running locally inside docker containers. I want to be able to create a data view from the command line using the kibana api.
I took the request from [this official kibana guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/data-views-api-create.html) and (after working around some error messages) crafted the following curl request:

```
curl -k -d @request.json -u elastic:password -H "kbn-xsrf: anything" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5601/api/data_views/data_view
```

the request.json contains

```
{
  "data_view": {
     "title": "logstash-test",
     "name": "My Logstash Data View"
  }
}
```

The resulting error message is

```
{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"[request body.data_view.title]: expected value of type [string] but got [undefined]"}
```

I don't know where this error is coming from and googling leads to no insight.

1. Is this an error related to my request (e.g. an error in my request.json) or is this inside kibana?
2. How can I avoid that error?

Comment: You've removed the `-H "Content-type: application/json"` from that doc's recommendation (as well as changing commandline data to a file). I don't know kibana specifically, but most HTTP servers or apps don't work if you send a request body without specifying the correct mediatype, and `-d` by default specifies `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which is not at all the correct mediatype here.